# EU citizen moving to the UK. Need a 2021 update

Tags: united-kingdom, working

This is for a EU citizen who has never lived in the UK and is neither working for a UK company, nor has worked previously for one.

As 2021 (soon 2022), what are the regulations for moving to the UK for work?

Is registering as self-employed acceptable?
Would creating an ltd and working through it make things easier or would this be bending the rules?
Can they move there and just start searching for work? (staying less than 90 days in a 180 days period).

Answer (score 9):

> As 2021 (soon 2022), what are the regulations for moving to the UK for work?

For most EU citizens, this will not be possible without a sponsoring employer, which is excluded from consideration.  Another possibility that seems to be beyond the scope of the question is family-based immigration.

> Is registering as self-employed acceptable?

Registering as self-employed doesn't help one to qualify for a visa.

> Would creating an ltd and working through it make things easier or would this be bending the rules?

Setting up a new business can help one qualify for a visa, but the business must be "innovative" and must be endorsed by a sponsoring organization.

> Can they move there and just start searching for work? (staying less than 90 days in a 180 days period).

There is no 90/180 rule in British immigration law.  Visitors are typically admitted for six months at a time.  It is permissible to look for work as a visitor, but immigration officers seem not to know this, and there have been reports of EU citizens being denied entry to the UK under these circumstances.  Regardless, anyone who does find work while in the UK as a visitor is prohibited from working in the UK.  Visitors are also prohibited from switching to another visa category, so it is necessary to leave the UK, apply for a work visa, and wait for the visa to be granted before returning to the UK and starting the job.

The UK has an online visa check tool that [listed five possibilities when I used the example of an Austrian citizen wanting to start a business](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/austria/work/longer_than_six_months/business):

- start-up or innovator visa: for one of these visas you need an "innovative" business idea that "must be something that’s different from anything else on the market," which you will need to demonstrate by getting an endorsement from an approved endorsing body.
- global talent visa: to qualify, you must be a "leader or potential leader" in academia or research, in arts or culture, or in digital technology.
- representative of an overseas business visa "if you work for an overseas company and you’re planning to set up your first UK branch or subsidiary."
- investor (tier I) visa "if you want to invest £2 million or more in the UK."

Comment: "Regardless, anyone who does find work while in the UK as a visitor is prohibited from working in the UK." Violating this rule will make it a lot harder to get a new visa, since they keep track of such violations for years. Don't even try.

Comment: @Quora Feans Employers in the UK are required to check a job applicant’s right to work https://www.gov.uk/check-job-applicant-right-to-work before employing them. Setting up a limited company (overseas *or* UK-based) doesn’t give you the right to work in the UK without a visa, other than to carry out the business-related activities any visitor is allowed to do https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-visitor-permitted-activities

Comment: *and there have been reports of EU citizens being denied entry to the UK under these circumstances* => if this is a concern OP could just fly to the UK via Ireland. The Irish cannot deny them entry and the Ireland->UK flight doesn't have immigration checks normally. This is a completely legal loophole that will remain as long as Ireland is both in the EU and the Common Travel Area.

Comment: @JonathanReez There is no loophole. For non-Irish EU citizens: **deemed leave** (Article 4) is granted when entering the UK from Ireland. [Travelling between the UK and Ireland, Isle of Man, Guernsey or Jersey - GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/travelling-between-the-uk-and-ireland-isle-of-man-guernsey-or-jersey): *You can be in the UK for **up to 6 months on your first visit from Ireland**. This time starts from the date you entered the UK. You can prove the date you entered the UK by, for example, your ticket or boarding pass. ...You cannot do any paid or unpaid work*

Comment: @JonathanReez [Your rights within the Common Travel Area](https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/government_in_ireland/ireland_and_the_uk/common_travel_area_between_ireland_and_the_uk.html): *Common Travel Area rights can only be exercised **by citizens of Ireland and the UK**. If you are not a citizen of Ireland or the UK, you **cannot** exercise Common Travel Area rights*.

Comment: @Mark the loophole is that you may enter the UK as many times as you please without ever seeing UK border control. You will see Irish border control but they cannot deny you entry as an EU citizen. So for all intents and purposes anyone who’s nervous about passing through UK immigration may entirely avoid doing so. Obviously this doesn’t mean you should use this to break UK immigration law but it could be helpful in edge case situations.

Comment: @JonathanReez I don’t see how entering the UK via the CTA is particularly helpful to the situation the OP is asking about. Doesn’t matter how often they pop backwards and forwards, they *still* can’t work while in the UK. Not even on a remote basis other than very limited activities eg answering emails.

Comment: @Traveller correct! However phoog mentions that even mentioning that you'll be looking for work to the immigration officer could land them in hot water, even though *looking* and *interviewing* is completely legal. So I'm suggesting they could avoid this issue altogether by booking a flight via Ireland. I don't know how big of a deal it is, but if its really a major sticking point I'd take the safe route.

Comment: @JonathanReez Ah, ok I see. Citizens of EU countries can normally use the e-gates, it’s probably unlikely the OP would have a landing interview at all. unless the e-gates weren’t operating for some reason or perhaps if the OP’s pattern of entering the UK flagged up as unusual.

Comment: @Traveller good point, [asked a follow up question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/169720/what-are-the-odds-of-having-to-see-a-uk-immigration-agent-for-someone-eligible-t).